# SQL finding course name from course code

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, `students` and `courses`. In the students table each student has a course code and in the courses table I have course codes with their names.

How can I return the course name when running the query?

So for example if I run a basic `SELECT * FROM Students` it says **"Jimmy | Computing"** instead of **"Jimmy | 12390814"**

Comment: This is a tangent to the question, but is it sensible in your case for students to be associated with only a single course?

Answer (score 4):

`JOIN` both tables. Try something like this,

```
SELECT   a.*, b.courseName
FROM     students a
         INNER JOIN courses b
               ON a.courseCode = b.courseCode
-- WHERE ....
```